# Check availability in Google Calendar API with Moment js iteration

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to code an appointment scheduler backend (with node.js) which checks what available time slots there are on the calendar (using Google Calendar API). Then takes that query and passes it to the *date* function. Once it has the query, the function creates an array of available time slots of 30 minutes, while checking if that time range is in the calendar's busy query. If the time range of the slot is between another event, it should move on and not push it to the array.

My problem comes when I have some occupied slots and it only compares the minutes, not the hour.

```
  function date(req,res,hours, events){

  var slots = [];
  
  const reqDay = moment(req.body.time);
  var rightNow  = moment(reqDay).hours(hours.start);
  var cutoff =  moment(reqDay).hours(hours.end)
  var duration = moment.duration({'minutes' : 30});
  
 
  for( rightNow ; rightNow.isBefore(cutoff) ; rightNow.add(duration) ){
    // Check if we're going beyond the daily cutoff, go to the next day
    if(rightNow.isAfter(moment(rightNow).hour(hours.end))){
      rightNow.add(1, 'days').hour(hours.start);
    }
    const range1 = moment.range(rightNow, moment(rightNow).add(30, 'minutes'))
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i ++ ) {
      const prevRange = moment.range(events[i][0], events[i][1])
      if(range1.overlaps(prevRange)){
        console.log(rightNow)
        rightNow.add(duration)
      }else {
        if (i = events.length) {
          slots.push(rightNow.format('HH:mm'));
        }else {
          i ++
        }
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(slots)
  res.json(slots);
}
```

When I retrieve the **busy query** from google calendar I get this console log:
(These are the busy)

```
  [
  [
    Moment<2020-10-12T10:30:00-03:00>,
    Moment<2020-10-12T13:15:00-03:00>
  ],
  [
    Moment<2020-10-12T16:30:00-03:00>,
    Moment<2020-10-12T17:30:00-03:00>
  ]
]
```

But when I console log the **slots** I get this:

```
[
  '10:00', '11:00',
  '12:00', '13:00',
  '13:30', '14:00',
  '14:30', '15:00',
  '15:30', '16:00',
  '16:30', '17:00',
  '17:30'
]
```

What am I missing?